# How can I disable end user sorting of the XtraTreeList?

Tags: devexpress, xtratreelist

I am displaying a fixed sequence in the tree list along with some values and clicking on the header will sort it by the value in the column that belongs to the header.

I haven't found any obvious property of the XtraTreeList that would disallow this sorting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sorting is disabled per column. You cannot disable for the whole tree list.

Answer (score 7):

For each column of your TreeList, turn off `AllowSort` - it's one of the subproperties listed under `OptionsColumn`.